# Limit column text size like in SQL

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to limit text size in cassandra like you would do in sql when creating a table?

```
username character varying(20)
```

My CQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE users(user_id uuid PRIMARY KEY, username text, date_created 
bigint, profile_pic text, num_followers integer, name text);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to limit text size in cassandra like you would do in sql when creating a table?

No, Cassandra does not allow you to limit the size of a VARCHAR/TEXT when creating a table.

> `user_id uuid PRIMARY KEY,`

Out of curiosity, why is `user_id` (a UUID) the sole PRIMARY KEY?  Do you need to support a lot of queries by `user_id`?

If not, then you should consider switching it to partition on something that provides a little more query flexibility, and maybe use `user_id` as a clustering key (to ensure uniqueness).

Comment: Just new to cassandra so still learning! Thanks for the advice

Comment: @WHOATEMYNOODLES No worries!  Glad I could help!